# Android Update Canvas(Keeping old screen too)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am drawing lines(free drawing) on the canvas by storing points in a queue and then painting the entire queue on the canvas. The performance deteriorates when the queue becomes large, as I am painting the entire set of points again from the starting of the queue.

Is there a way, I can draw only the new data on the canvas, without the need for redrawing the entire queue, just like update() method in Java Applets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar thing, but drawing circles. Basically, the drawing happens on an offscreen bitmap, which is then drawn on the system canvas. See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/Dgj3gLKC)

Answer (score -2):

Try using this to lock your canvas, write the data and then unlock and post the data.

```
Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
// Your code here
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```